# generate wsdl url successful,return null while access soap server fucntion in php

Tags: php, soap

I'new here and poor in English so I try to express my problem while learning webservice in php.
question:
  call soap function ,return null,actually I set return string in class.

HandleClass.php(soap server request function):

```
class HandleClass{

   public function say(string $url):string
   {
    return $url;
   }
}
```

wsdl uri:http://localhost/API/RequestMethod/soap/wsdl/RunServer.php?wsdl

```
<definitions xmlns:wsdlns="http://tempuri.org/wsdl/" xmlns:typens="http://tempuri.org/xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:stk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap-toolkit/wsdl-extension" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="myTestServer" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/wsdl/">
<types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified"> </schema>
</types>
<message name="say">
<part name="url" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="sayResponse">
<part name="say" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="say2">
<part name="token" type="xsd:string"/>
<part name="param" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<message name="say2Response">
<part name="say2" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
<portType name="myTestServerPortType">
<operation name="say" parameterOrder="url">
<input message="wsdltns:say"/>
<output message="wsdltns:sayResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="say2" parameterOrder="param">
<input message="wsdltns:say2"/>
<output message="wsdltns:say2Response"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="myTestServerBinding" type="wsdltns:myTestServerPortType">
<stk:binding preferredEncoding="utf-8"/>
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="say">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/action/myTestServer.say"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:myTestServer" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:myTestServer" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="say2">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/action/myTestServer.say2"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:myTestServer" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:myTestServer" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="myTestServer">
<port name="myTestServerPort" binding="wsdlns:myTestServerBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost/API/RequestMethod/soap/wsdl/RunServer.php"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

soapClient.php (get functions)

```
$soap = new \SoapClient('http://localhost/API/RequestMethod/soap/wsdl/RunServer.php?wsdl');
try {
//    $a = $soap->__soapCall('say',[123]);
    $a = $soap->__getFunctions();
    var_dump($a);exit;
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

response:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "string say(string $url)"
  [1]=>
  string(41) "string say2(string $token, string $param)"
}
```

soapClient.php:

```
$soap = new \SoapClient('http://localhost/API/RequestMethod/soap/wsdl/RunServer.php?wsdl');
try {
   $a = $soap->say('url');
    var_dump($a);exit;
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}
```

response:
null

Answer (score 0):

maybe url is not valid, or as i have used SOAP only with one webservice it required array with key and value, maybe this will work?

```
    $soap = new 
    \SoapClient('http://localhost/API/RequestMethod/soap/wsdl/RunServer.php?wsdl');
    try {
      $a = $soap->say(array('url' => $given_url));
      var_dump($a);exit;
    } catch (\Throwable $e) {
      var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: I try it as you said, but it failed....It's strange, I used it successful before,but now it somehow couldn't work. response:  <b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>F:\www\API\RequestMethod\soap\wsdl\SopClient.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: You can give any string, maybe the string has to contain http/https or something? sorry i cant be more usefull